# What does geth need RAM for on a non-mining node?

Tags: go-ethereum

I was running a private Ethereum chain on a couple of non-mining Raspberry Pis and encountered quite high and increasing RAM usage.

[image: g]I understand that there was a memory leak with geth versions before 1.9 that made RAM usage increase excessively but I do not understand why geth would need any RAM at all if I am not mining. So the question:

What is RAM used for on non-mining nodes in a blockchain? Is the RAM usage generally meant to increase over time or should it be stable at a certain level?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Indeed there are memory-leak issues with running a lot of Crypto-Clients.